# Example of using "cleaned" Javascript in an Angular 2 Template?

Tags: angular

I understand that to use Javascript within an Angular 2 application, it's necessary to mark the script as clean by using the DomSanitizer's bypassSecurityTrustScript method.

Once's that is done, however, how do you place that script into the template?  I believe you have to bind it to something within the template, but how?

Comment: where did you read about that?

Comment: I would recommend the Angular tutorial with JavaScript (even though TypeScript is recommended): https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/tutorial/

Comment: The only documentation I've seen about BypassSecurityTrustScript is from within the [domSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) documentation.  Again, though, I can't find an example of actually using the method.

Comment: Also, I've seen many examples of using the BypassSecurityTrustHTML and BypassSecurityTrustResourceURL; just not the Script sanitizer.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do this like this and that it can't be handled otherly?

Comment: Yes, I'm pulling existing Javascript from a database that interacts with elements in the DOM.  I'm just surprised that the BypassSecurityTrustScript method is available but there are really no examples of how to use it.